# Unable to SSH into ubuntu server

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-18.04

I get `connection reset by peer` error when I try to SSH into my Ubuntu server using my mobile ISP. However, this error 'disappears' when I change to another ISP. Please what is the likely cause and how do I solve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. For Ubuntu support go to https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command and try again.

```
    sudo dhclient
```

Answer (score -1):

For security reasons, the ssh client normally doesn't get any useful diagnostic info for failed connections. If you can access your server logs, you may find useful info there. On my Ubuntu server, I see that here: /var/log/auth.log